# utf-8 problem in using jquery autocomplete tags

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, utf-8

hey mates . recently i used jquery auto-complete tag

http://devthought.com/projects/jquery/textboxlist/

everything goes fine except utf-8 tag suggesting , only English tags are suggested

i guess something goes wrong with script lines 
it works fine with English tags but not with multi byte languages like Persian

Comment: Why do you escape the single quotes in your JavaScript code?

Comment: its like  echo'<script>'  thats why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably line 212 in the TextboxList.Autocomplete.js is to blame:

```
regexp = new RegExp('\\b' + escapeRegExp(search), insensitive ? 'i' : '');
```

That's looking for the given character after a word boundary. But word boundaries are dependent on recognition of word characters, and JavaScript RegExp's list of word characters is just the ASCII alphanumerics plus `_`. Because RegExp knows nothing about Unicode this won't work where the word begins with a non-ASCII character.

You could try getting rid of the `\\b` in which case it would match any suggestion with the given string anywhere inside it, not just at the start of words.

Comment: wow , i was going to  answer my own question ( just exactly what u said )  and asking how to solve this now , so it will list anything that has that word not the first word , so now how to solve this ?

Comment: How about something like `'(^|[ !-/:-@[-XXX{-~])'+escapeRegExp(search)`? Note, replace `XXX` with a backquote, I can't type it in comments!

Answer (score 1):

Your HTTP header is wrong. It should be:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
```

You can also shorten your code and do the sorting with MySQL:

```
$sql = 'SELECT `tag` FROM `'.$prefix.'_tags` ORDER BY `tag`';
$result = $db->sql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 500 Internal Server Error');
    echo mysql_error();
    exit;
}

$response = array();
$i = 0;
while ($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result)) {
    $response[] = array($i++, $row);
}
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: thanks for shortening my code , although ur code doesnt work at all , maybe u didnt know about my sql part . 


but my problem is not getting persian ( utf-8 ) tags , and only english ones ,  its so simple how can i did anything wrong ! 

<input type=\"text\"  name='$name' id='$name' size='20' value=\"\" />

Comment: @farshad Ghazanfari: Where is your tag filtering anyway? Where do you include the user’s input?

Comment: i wrote a class for it , and add it to my form , 
i did not add any filter to tags  just read them from sql and ...
Can we use different method instead of using json ?

Comment: @farshad Ghazanfari: I meant your script is just putting all of your tags out as there is no further restriction i.e. no filtering that the tags must begin with a certain sequence (that what the user has already entered).

Answer (score 1):

Your content-type header is somewhat wrong. First, it should be `content-type:something; charset=something`, that is, `content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8`.

But it is actually suggested to use content-type `application/json`, see here [What is the correct JSON content type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type)

So, you could do it like this

```
header("Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```

Comment: hey thanks ,  i did used that  header  but nothing worked , then i changed type , uh im tired i can't find the bug

Answer (score 1):

Probably line 215 in the TextboxList.Autocomplete.js is to blame:

```
if (regexp.test(values[i][1])) newvals.push(values[i]);
```

covert it to

```
if (values[i][1].indexOf(escapeRegExp(search)) != -1) newvals.push(values[i]);
```

Bobince (first answer) right, the problem is in line 212, but resolved it can be in line 215